# How to display user information after successful login using NodeJS and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I am using Cloud Firestore as my database, all the frontend is in HTML, CSS, JS and I'm working on the backend part. I successfully built the 2 register functions (for doctors and patients) and login (a single login for all users). There are 2 pages/routes that the project needs to navigate to after successful login. Doctor-dashboard, if it is a doctor who is logging in and Patient-dashboard if it is patient. I'm using username of the user to log in. The problem is that I don't know how to display the User's name (not username, which is a different attribute) on the dashboard page. The user information should come from database after successful login, which I need to show on the HTML page to which the login post-request redirects. I'm sharing the login and register functions and HTML code for dashboard page too. Please help.

index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors');
const config = require('./config');
const path = require('path');
const firebase = require('firebase');
const routes = require('./routes');

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));
var fb = firebase.initializeApp(config.firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore(fb);

app.use('/', routes)
app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
console.log("Running at port 3000")

app.post('/register-patient', (req, res) => {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  db.collection('users').doc(username).set({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
    category: "patient"
  })
  .then(() => {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", username);
      res.redirect('/patient-dashboard.html')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
  })
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  var docRef = db.collection("users").doc(username);
  docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      var info = doc.data();
      if (info.password === password) {
        var category = info.category;
        if (category === 'doctor') {
          res.send(username);
          res.redirect('/doctor-dashboard.html');
        } else {
          res.redirect('/patient-dashboard.html');
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Wrong password");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No such document");
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  })
})
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
});

router.get('/login.html', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/login.html'))
});

router.get('/register.html', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/register.html'))
});

router.get('/doctor-register.html', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/doctor-register.html'))
})

router.get('/doctor-dashboard.html', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/doctor-dashboard.html'))
})

router.get('/patient-dashboard.html', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/patient-dashboard.html'))
})

module.exports = router
```

patient-dashboard.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AARC-PLUS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Fontawesome CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a name="home"></a>
    <!-- Main Wrapper -->
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <!-- Header -->
        <script src="assets/js/header-patient.js"></script>
        <!-- /Header -->
            
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <!-- Profile Sidebar -->
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 theiaStickySidebar">
                        <div class="profile-sidebar">
                            <div class="widget-profile pro-widget-content">
                                <div class="profile-info-widget">
                                    <a href="#" class="booking-doc-img">
                                        <img src="assets/img/patients/patient.jpg" alt="User Image">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="profile-det-info">
                                        <h3 name="name">Richard Wilson</h3>
                                        <div class="patient-details">
                                            <h5><i class="fas fa-birthday-cake"></i> 24 Jul 1983, 38 years</h5>
                                            <h5 class="mb-0"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> Newyork, USA</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I'm not pasting the whole HTML code here as it is too long and I think it would be good to pin-point the exact location which I want to be modified. It is `<h3 name="name">Richard Wilson</h3>` which I want to be modified as per user's information.

Please let me know if u any need more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to this. Thanks to [Gajanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12065756/gajanan) for pointing me in the correct direction. In his answer, he has used `res.redirect()` which was giving an error. Instead I installed `ejs` module using `npm install ejs` and set the my view engine to ejs in `index.js` file.

Then I renamed all the html files to `<filename>.ejs`, created a directory named `views` and put all the `.ejs` files in that directory.

After that I added this line `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` to my `index.js` file and changed the line `res.redirect('/doctor-dashboard.html')` to `res.render('doctor-dashboard', {name: *Value*})` and used [Gajanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12065756/gajanan)'s suggested modification in corresponding ejs file, i.e, `<h3><%= name%></h3>`, and voila. It worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 res.redirect('/doctor-dashboard.html',{"user":username);

 <h3 name="name"><%=user.name%></h3>
```

Comment: Gives this error
```express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead```